# How do I add the user's name to my commandline?

Tags: zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

Currently an example line of my terminal will start with `-> ~ git:(master)`

But I'd like to update it to use the current user too: `-> [tom] ~ git:(master)`

Right now I'm using oh-my-zsh and I thought to override it, I'd add something to my .zshrc file, but I can't seem to find out where/what to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`zsh prompt expansion sequence`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html), found in the manual page for [`zshmisc`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zshmisc/).

If you're using `oh-my-zsh` it's a bit tricky: you need to figure out what theme you're using, then modify it to include the right prompt sequence. The themes are kept in `$HOME/.oh-my-zsh/themes`. If you're really stuck, you could include the theme you're using in your question :)

The prompt expansion you're probably looking for is `%n`, which expands to `$USERNAME`.

Comment: I just switched to a new theme, but checked this out and it looks like it would've worked.